# Llamar valor de un SUM() dentro de un foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Buen dia comunidad, tengo una duda demasiado básica pero no he encontrado como resolverla.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    $pxl = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(puntos) FROM calculoInt where idPerf=:idP");
    $pxl->bindParam(':idP',$idP)
    $pxl->execute();

<?php foreach ($pxl as $punts) { echo $punts[''] }?>
```

Como hago para escribir el valor de la suma obtenida dentro del select dependiendo del id (El cual ya es definido antes en mi programa) que se va a encontrar dentro del foreach. Solo necesito saber como mostrar esa suma de puntos ya obtenida varias veces por ese usuario.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes usar un alias dentro de la query `SUM(puntos) as puntos`, para luego acceder a ese valor asi `echo $punts['puntos']`

Comment: Gracias, muy util tu respuesta!

Comment: @AníbalJorquera escribela como respuesta para que no se quede en el comentario

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas gracias por la recomendación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acceder de forma directa puedes agregar un alias (`as puntos`) a la operación `SUM` dentro de tu sentencia `select` de esta forma puedes acceder directamente al valor de tu alias.

Ejemplo:

```
$pxl = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(puntos) as puntos FROM calculoInt where idPerf=:idP");
$pxl->bindParam(':idP',$idP)
$pxl->execute();

<?php foreach ($pxl as $punts) { echo $punts['puntos'] }?>
```

Comment: Tienes que ver pk no creo que el SUM devuelva mas de un resultado tal vez quieras ejecutar la consulta pero que devuelva un solo row